# REST ful java web service on heroku?

Tags: java, rest, heroku

how to write java REST Web service and Deploy it on heroku? Till now I just  worked on simple java application on heroku,  first time I am  trying to deploy a web service.

Answer (score 8):

[Spring MVC's REST support](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/) is one option that is pretty easy to use.  Or you can use [Play Framework's REST support](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/routes).  Or there are [many other options](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20rest%20servers).  They should virtually all run on Heroku so try a few and see what works for you.

Comment: Rest web service  which is returning a string response like “java code is running”  when I  run it on my local . i am using grizzly server  to run that application  when I run main method , I can access the url http://localhost:9998/run/java  which will shows the same response in web browser. Now I am pushing my application on heroku  it gives me the url   http://stormy-dusk-2050.herokuapp.com/ . i am not getting how to get the same response from this url .
 if I run  - heroku run “sh target/bin/webapp” it gives me  http://localhost:29988/run/java Which I am not able to access in browser .

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of a JAX-RS REST service, complete with Procfile and README for deploying to Heroku (not much to do).

https://github.com/jesperfj/jax-rs-upload-file

It uses Grizzly as embedded server and is super lightweight. Let me know what path you decide to take. Curious about what works best for you.

Comment: i am using your mathod . from my local  working  rest url is http://localhost:9998/run/java.  what the url i will get from heroku which will work for me.

Comment: I have one Rest web service which is returning a string response like “java code is running” when I run it on my local . i am using grizzly server to run that application when I run main method , I can access the url http://localhost:9998/run/java which will shows the same response in web browser. Now I am pushing my application on heroku it gives me the url http://stormy-dusk-2050.herokuapp.com/ . i am not getting how to get the same response from this url . if I run - heroku run “sh target/bin/webapp” it gives me http://localhost:29988/run/java Which I am not able to access in browse